# How to create multiple uipickerview in tableview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

PickerView delegate method...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
        if (didSelectedRow ==1) 
        {
            strChkDistanceValue = [arrDistance objectAtIndex:row];
        }
        else 
        {
            strChkDateRangeValue = [arrDateRange objectAtIndex:row];
        }
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    if(didSelectedRow ==1)
    {
        return [arrDistance count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [arrDateRange count];
    }
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    if(didSelectedRow ==1)
    {
        strChkarray =@"arrDistance";
        return [arrDistance objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else
    {
        strChkarray =@"arrDateRange";
        return [arrDateRange objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}
```

above code I am use...
I am using the `pickerview` in `tableview`... there are two picker views...
when i am use the first picker view the first picker view array shows in picker when i am select 3rd row in picker view after i select the 2nd picker view then show the second array list but second array list show start with 3rd row...same to 1st picker...
but i want to show at first row of array in pickerviw..
please help me...

Thanks & regards
Rahul Virja

Answer (score 0):

You should use below method of UIPickerView to select a particular row.

```
- (void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Comment: i want to see the list in array at start...in first pickerview i get the list at starting but when i am select other row...and goto in second picker view i not show the list at starting...

Comment: when you decide to display second picker or new data to the picker give above call like,
[pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];